# Finding peak values from an array in a given range

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The method `getPeakCount` takes an `int` array and a range (`int`) as an input and returns the number of integers that are greater than all the elements to either side for the given range.

For example, consider an array `{1,4,2,6,4,5,10,8,7,11}` and range `2`. The result should be `3`, as `{..,4,2,6,4,5,..}`, `{..,4,5,10,8,7,..}` and `{..,8,7,11}` satisfy this condition. These satisfy the condition because `6`, `10` and `11` are all greater than the 2 elements to both their left and right.

Note that for the the corner elements like `1` and `11`, there's no need to check the left and right side respectively.

My code is below, but it is not correct.

```
static int getPeakCount(int[] arr, int R) {
        int result=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]&&arr[i]>arr[i+2]){
                result++;
            }
             } //-----> closing if(i==0) condition
            else if(i==arr.length-1){
                if(arr[i]>arr[i-1]&&arr[i]>arr[i-2]){
                    result++;
                }

            }
            else if(i+R>arr.length){
                if(arr[i]>arr[i-R] && arr[i]>arr[i-R+1]){
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    result++;
                }
            }
            else{

                if(arr[i]>arr[i+1] && arr[i]>arr[i+2] && arr[i]>arr[i-R] && arr[i]>arr[i-R+1]){
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't know whether I'm going in the right direction or not, and for last if condition it's throwing an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

P.S. Don't consider this code as solution to remove errors from this. This is just the attempt I tried.

Comment: It __would__ throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` given that you attempt to access `arr[len]` and `arr[len+1]`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I already know that and also said that i'm not able to solve this problem and need some help regarding that

Comment: You may have a mistake in your first if of `if(i==0){`, doesn't seem like that should be there, if it needs to be there, then perhaps the loop above it doesn't, you'll only get one iteration out of the loop.

Comment: I want to know what am i missing in this. except that if condition. what are other scenarios i need to consider to solve this problem.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove...that if condition is for the first element. as I dont have to compare that element with the previous elements as it doenst have any.

Comment: if(i==0){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]&&arr[i]>arr[i+2]){. This would throw an exception if your arr length is less than 3.

Comment: @abhishek..for the time being im considering the fixed length array which is {1,4,2,6,4,5,10,8,7,11}

Comment: what is the value of R?

Comment: R=2 and also I've updated the pseudo code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly the condition is the integers should satisfy and how the chosen integers / ranges (you seem to be giving ranges but you ask for integers) satisfy the condition?

Comment: @Dukeling now for the give array if the range is 2 that means finding count of such integers in the array who are max in the sub-array containing 2 element from right and left side of that element.

Comment: @Victor I still don't understand. Can you explain how your chosen integers satisfy the condition?

Comment: please read comments which are below the solution provided by timbo. if you will still face any problem understanding the situation please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the right idea, and devnull is right. You just need to check the center, so change the loop to start at 1 and end 1 before the end. I commented out the end conditions. I think this does what you were asking, though not 100% sure I understood what you were after.

I should add, I use variables like l (left), r (right) and c (center) for clarity. You can make this much faster if you have large arrays. There is also redundancy in that it checks conditions it should know are already false (if I find a peak, I should skip the next value, as it can't also be a peak).

```
public class PeakChecker {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 10, 8, 7, 11};

        System.out.println(nPeaks(array, 2));
    }

    static int nPeaks(int[] array, int range) {

        // Check for special cases
        if (array == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int result = 0, l, r;

        // Check main body
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            boolean isPeak = true;
            // Check from left to right
            l = Math.max(0, i - range);
            r = Math.min(array.length - 1, i + range);
            for (int j = l; j <= r; j++) {
                // Skip if we are on current
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                    isPeak = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPeak) {
                System.out.println("Peak at " + i + " = " + array[i]);
                result++;
                i += range;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the correct solution. take the situation in the array. when the arr[i]=6, 6>2 and 4 which are its two left neighbors as well as 6>4 and 5 which are its right neighbors same goes for 10 and for 11, it doesn't have right elements so i've to compare only left elements 8,7 and so it satisfies the condition so it also counts. so result should be 3.

Comment: I'm confused. The result IS 3. It finds: 4 (the first 4), 6 and 10.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm understanding now . . . The range is how many neighbours it is greater than! Got you. Easy fix.

Comment: yes. cause 6,10,11 are peak values in their respective range. they are max in their 2 left and 2 right neighbors(where 2 is the range).           P.S. for 11 only consider 2 elements from left side.

Comment: ...at last somebody understood what i'm trying to say. thanks for understanding.1 up from me.

Comment: OK, NOW it should work. I left the println in there for debugging.

Comment: Cool. I added some speed improvements. Small, but could help with big arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The last if condition shall throw exception when `i == arr.length - 2`.

This is because `arr[i+2]` in that case is out of bounds.

Comment: I know that already. please read comments. I want to know different cases to consider for the solution of this problem or the way this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException stack trace, it will tell you a line of code the error happened on. Look on that line of code and you'll probably see arr[i+1] or arr[i-1] or something. Certainly, at least one access on that line will be out of bounds. That's the problem.

Comment: except that what are diffent conditions to consider for this problem thats what i tried to ask here

Comment: @Victor then you should have asked that, and posted the line you knew the problem was happening on. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: read my second sentence after the code. you will come to know that i know why im facing that problem but wanted to know whether the conditions are fully covered or not. sorry if i confused you.